# Trigger Multiple API calls with observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Trigger multiple api calls in a loop as below:

```
for (let item of items) {
    resource.post(item).pipe(map(() => {
      ...
    }
}
```

But the above one fails because of asynchronous behavior. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code could understand that RxJS is used, in which we have Zip operator, that emits all the values from observable as an array, something like

```
let requestObservables = []
for (let item of items) {
  requestObservables.push(resource.post(item));
  return zip(...requestObservables).pipe(mergeMap(res => { ....//response actions });
 }
```